# PHP: allow only two IP addresses at the same time

Tags: php, ip-address

I want my website to be accessed from only two IP addresses.
when ever the site is accessed by more than 2 IP addresses it will shoe an error.
can any body done this in php please help me

thank you

Comment: Do you mean more than 2 id addresses *simultaneously*?

Comment: Actualy my website is need to be accessed from only 2 IP's at a time.
When ever the 3rd ip comes in the question it will shows an error.
when one from 2 ip's currently accessing site logged off then only the third IP can get the access of the site.

Comment: You'd want to configure your web server in this manner, if that's what you really want, but I'd hazard a guess that implications would be more severe than you anticipate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the number of concurrent users you need some kind of sessions stored in a database.
Then, when a new user logs in, check if there are already two sessions from different ips and in this case throw an error.

Note that you MUST make sessions expire quickly if someone is inactive so he doesn't prevent someone else from logging in just because he did not logout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but i am confused in one thing that how would I expired the session if someone is inactive?
I mean how would I get to know ?

Comment: Whenever a logged in user does something, you store the timestamp.
Then you can ignore inactive sessions (`(time() - lastactivity) > delay`) and/or delete them easily.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '212.100.232.111' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '212.100.232.112'){
 die('No access');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict all visitors to certain IPs, the easiest/fastest way would be doing so in your web server, e.g. with an Apache .htaccess, instead of doing it in PHP:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow From 1.2.3.4
Allow From 5.6.7.8
```

Comment: NO I dnt need to restrict all visitors to certain IPs

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the address of the incoming connection, and test against it to perform the appropriate redirection or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` superglobal variable: this should give you the IP address from which the client's request originated. Just test to see whether it's allowed and show your error message if not.